# Is there a Sphinx extension that provides a configurable toc (or more configurable toctree) in templates?

Tags: python-sphinx

The Sphinx [toc](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/templating.html#toc) template variable provides an HTML list of headings in the current document (i.e. current page).

However, for my purposes, I need a list of headings:

- excluding the document title
- of limited depth

I'm hoping to find an extension that will generate a local toc, with the additional control I need. Another approach would be a modified version of [toctree](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/templating.html#toctree) (that produces the global table of contents) that would generate the HTML list starting only from the current node.

Comment: I'm not aware of the answer. As you correctly said, toc is a variable containing full local ToC as <ul>, so you can't limit depth. contents:: directive generates local ToC as <ul> too, but can limit depth. For both ways, ToC always starts with document title.

Comment: I'm having some difficulty wrapping my head around the restriction...The TOC is usually a reST directive (no Sphinx needed thus far). The limited depth restriction should be satisfiable with the toctree, do you mean using a toctree inside 1 given `.rst` file that only lists the contents of the file it is in? (Or does this positively need to be a templating solution?)

Comment: The `toctree` template can be found in `venv38\Lib\site-packages\sphinx\templates\apidoc\toc.rst_t` is suppose you could costumize that template?! I don't recall seeing any question on SO that customizes the template, so it's an interesting perspective.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`contents` directive](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#table-of-contents).

> The "contents" directive generates a table of contents (TOC) in a topic. Topics, and therefore tables of contents, may occur anywhere a section or transition may occur. Body elements and topics may not contain tables of contents.
>
> Here's the directive in its simplest form:
>
> ```
> .. contents::
> ```

Comment: Sadly this isn't going to work. I don't need to generate a table of contents, I need access to a variable a in a template context.